# Reduce size of sveltekit app deployed with node-adapter

Tags: javascript, deployment, node-modules, filesize, sveltekit

I have written a sveltekit app that I would like to deploy for instance on AlwaysData.

On the AlwaysData servers I can use up to 100Mo. I thought this would be plenty for the very small app I have written. But it is not the case : my app is more than 400Mo.

I looked into it and noticed two things :

- after building the app, there still remains a node_modules folder that is not bundled into the app.
- this node_modules folder is more than 400Mo although I only use a few simple libraries.

Hence my question:

- is there a way to bundle the node_module packages into my app? This would keep only the necessary stuff which is only a few kilobytes.
- or is there a way to tell javascript to import the minified version of the package in the dist folder when in production.

Following are the libraries I use and the size they should be according to bundlephobia :

- @primsa/client : 233B
- @supercharge/request-ip : 3.8kB
- axios : 17.6kB
- ramda : 53.4kB
- sprintf-js : 3.5kB

So how does an app that should take less than a 100kB end up taking 400MB ? Even from an environmental point of view, this looks a bit annoying...

Comment: did you find any improvement?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to deploy the build folder nothing more.